# Wrapping mysql -e "cmd" does not work

Tags: bash

I'm trying to wrap this kind of command `mysql -e "SHOW TABLES;"` into a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) function.

The command I'm trying is

```
mysql -hremote_id -uuser -ppass db -e "SHOW TABLES;"
```

Obviously this works as expected. But for some reason I don't understand, this displays the help output:

```
run ()
{
    local cmd=$1;
    shift;
    ${cmd} $@
}

run mysql "-hremote_id -uuser -ppass db -e \"SHOW TABLES;\""
run mysql '-hremote_id -uuser -ppass db -e ""SHOW TABLES;"'
```

Both of the two last lines display the help page:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.57, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.2
Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: You need more quotes: `"${cmd}" "$@"`.

Comment: Although if your "list" of arguments is really in a single string, you are doomed from the start.

Comment: Why assign `$1` to `$cmd`, shift and then `${cmd} $@` (ignoring the missing quotes) instead of just `"$@"`?!

Comment: @Biffen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50004642/wrapping-mysql-e-cmd-does-not-work#comment87026330_50004852

Comment: @Biffen the whole wrapping thing is because we want the dry run feature :/

Comment: @smarber I don't see what that has to do with the shifting (maybe I'm missing something). Isn't e.g. `if dry ; then printf 'Would have run: %s\n' "$*" ; else "$@" ; fi` enough?

Comment: @Biffen that's because `run` handles redirection too, and it's basically through the second argument which needs to be set to `--redirect_output` for instance. So I thought I need to do some arguments separation there. There are maybe better ways, all suggestions are welcome of course :)

Comment: @smarber Ah, got it! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use more quotes in `run`:

```
run () {
  local cmd="$1"
  shift
  "$cmd" "$@"
}
```

and pass arguments individually:

```
run mysql -hremote_id -uuser -ppass db -e "SHOW TABLES;"
```

You might look at that and ask yourself "Why do I need `run` at all?" That's a very good question. I assume `run` is doing slightly more than just running the given command. But the principal holds: individual arguments should *remain* individual arguments. Otherwise, you need to use `eval`, and that requires a whole other level of care to use correctly and safely.

If you are manually packing the arguments into a string, stop doing that. Use an array:

```
opts=(-hremote_id -uuser -ppass db -e "Show TABLES;")
run mysql "${opts[@]}"
```

If you are receiving this single string from somewhere else, you have some significant redesign to do.

Comment: Thanks that works indeed! And you're right, `run` function is meant to dry-run if needed (based on an environment variable). It handles redirections too...